# Tsql how get the columns used in a stored procedure for a view in linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

I have a stored procedure in a mssql database that it uses data from a view in a linked server.
I need retrieve the information about the columns and their datatype of this view used in the stored procedure.

I have tried with this but not working:

```
 SELECT DatabaseName = Isnull(referenced_database_name, Db_name()),
       StoredProcedureName = 'spr_rpt_CustomerSurvey',
       SO.objecttype,
       ObjectName = referenced_entity_name,
       ColumnName = referenced_minor_name,
       OrdinalPosition = referenced_minor_id
FROM   sys.Dm_sql_referenced_entities('[dbo].[spr_rpt_CustomerSurvey]', 'OBJECT'
       ) R
       CROSS apply (SELECT ObjectType = ( CASE type_desc
                                            WHEN 'VIEW' THEN 'View'
                                            WHEN 'USER_TABLE'THEN'Table'
                                          END )
                    FROM   sys.objects
                    WHERE  object_id = R.referenced_id) SO
WHERE  referenced_minor_name IS NOT NULL
```

Some idea???
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) against a linked server, might work though...

Another option is `SELECT TOP 1 * INTO SomeTable FROM YourView;`

This will create a new table "SomeTable" where the view's result is written into. Now you can check columns and types of this table.

Is the linked server a SQL RDBMS too? Most SQL RDBMS support queries against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, in your case against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and be aware, that the view's name will be found under `TABLE_NAME` quite probably...

Answer (score 0):

View columns can be found in

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'view name'
```

TVF columns can be found in

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'view name'
```

If the view is on a linked server, you'll need to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS from the linked server

```
SELECT * FROM [linked server].[database name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'view name'
```